# Reading the column of DataFrame fails

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python 2.7 with Anaconda2. When I do a simple reading of a txt file into the dataframe (`df = pd.read_table("/home/testtab.txt",sep='\t',index_col=False)`) and then read one of the columns as follows (`df["col1"].head()`), it gives me an error (see below). 
Also the row index is present, while I expected to disable it with `index_col=False`.
The output of `df.columns` is the following:

```
Index([u'col1', u'col2'],dtype='object')
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c472f01c3482> in <module>()
----> 1 df["col1"].head()

/home/gooo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1996         else:
-> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1998 
   1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/home/gooo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2002         # get column
   2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2005 
   2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/home/gooo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1348         res = cache.get(item)
   1349         if res is None:
-> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
   1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1352             cache[item] = res

/home/gooo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3288 
   3289             if not isnull(item):
-> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3291             else:
   3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/home/gooo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
-> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'col1'
```

EDIT:

Output of `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7499900 entries, 0 to 7499899
Data columns (total 18 columns):
col1       object
col2       float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.0+ GB
```

Comment: what return `df.info()` ?

Comment: @jezrael: Please see my edit

Comment: Interesting. How works `df.col1` and `df['col1']` ?

Comment: The funny thing is that I can read `df[col2]`. So, it's the problem of `object`. How to convert objects to string? `df.col1.head()` gives me `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col1''`

Comment: I think if is possible problem with `head`, so if omit it, it works?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also I cannot do for instance `df[df["col1"]=="ABC"]`, because it fails as well.

Comment: Really interesting. What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: @jezrael: pandas: 0.18.1

Comment: and what about `print (df.loc[:, 'col1'])` ?

Comment: It tells `KeyError: 'the label [col1] is not in the [columns]'`, but it IS in the list of columns. The only difference is that it comes with `u` as `u'col1'`. Maybe the problem is with the file?

Comment: No, it means unicode. And `print df.columns.tolist()` return?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a space before or after "col1"?

Comment: Or dont use `set_index` from `col1` ?

Comment: @JulienMarrec - Yes, it is good idea, but OP write `Index([u'col1', u'col2'],dtype='object')` - there is no space (unfortunately)

Comment: @jezrael: What do you mean by "dont use set_index from col1"?

Comment: There is no space. I checked it.

Comment: In code something like `df = df.set_index('col1')`, but it is only idea. But if use `df.columns = ['col3','col4']` after reading, `df['col3']` work, right?

Comment: @jezrael: Yes, other columns except the FIRST ONE work fine. Very strange.. The command `set_index` gives me `KeyError: 'col1'`

Comment: If use `read_csv` - `df = pd.read_csv("/home/testtab.txt",sep='\t',index_col=False)` still same problem?

Comment: @jezrael: Yes, the same error. Is it possible to uso some other library to load txt and then pass it to pandas DataFrame?

Comment: I have a idea - can you upgrade pandas to last version `0.19.1`, restart `anaconda` if use it and test again?

Comment: @jezrael: Ok, let me test it.

Comment: @jezrael: Yupiiii. It works now!!! You're genius. Thank you so much!!! Please publish the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you, I add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem with pandas version `0.18.1`, after upgrade to `0.19.1` it works fine.

Maybe some bug I think.